# CenteredSlides and loop with swiper.js

Tags: swiper.js

Is there a way to have both centered slides and an infinite loop, along with thumbnails with swiper.js? I have the following settings, but when I add loop true it doesn't seem to work.

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
paginationClickable: true,
centeredSlides: true,
initialSlide:1,
speed:1200,
centeredSlides: true,
slidesPerView: 'auto'
```

http://machinas.com/wip/hugoboss/fall2014/startpage/variable-width/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

centeredSlides is not really compatible with Loop mode. Try to increase loopedSlides and loopAdditionalSlides parameters.
eg:

```
  centeredSlides: true
    loop: true
    loopAdditionalSlides: 100
```